# WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG default initialization

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, default-value

i am using WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG in my application for IE proxy config.

I am initializing in my constructor as this

memset( &proxyConfig, 0, sizeof(WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG) );

However when i ran my memory profiler I face "Un Initialized Memory Access".

I went into msdn and got the structure of WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG and even tried the below implementation. Still it did not work.

```
//proxyConfig.fAutoDetect = false;<br>
//proxyConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl = NULL;<br>
//proxyConfig.lpszProxy = NULL;<br>
//proxyConfig.lpszProxyBypass = NULL;<br>
```

Has anyone have suggestion for a best practice to initialize WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG in the code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG ieProxyConfig = {0};
```

there may be other errors,no because the initialize.